# WP hook changes view in admin

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post-type called `reference`. When I save a standard wp-post I would also like to save a copy of that post with the only difference is that it has post_type = '`reference`';

I am using the following hook:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'create_reference', 10, 3);
    function create_reference($id)
    {
        $post = get_post($id);
        $ref = $post;
        $ref->post_type = 'reference';
        wp_insert_post($ref);
        return $post // Seems that I need this line, otherwise the standard post wont save.
    }
```

This seems to work but also changes the view in wp-admin which is confusing. Even though i am creating the post in the standard post view. The view changes to the `reference` post-type view.

I do not understand why this is happening and how it can be avoided.
Thank you.

Comment: '$ref=$post;' simply references the $post, not make a copy of it. So you are actually changing the '$post' post type to 'reference', hence it goes to the custom view. You need to create a new post for the 'reference' post type.

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson! Now i have a better shot at making this work!